No library tips in VS Code Jupyter Notebook
I do not get tooltips and documentation for libraries in VS Code Jupyter Notebook:

I only get function signatures:

It works for Python libs like datetime:

How can I get function documentation in VS Code Jupyter Notebook?
Info

i am using WSL Ubuntu
I am using Jupyter Notebook running in localhost via pipenv
I copy and paste the localhost url with token from my terminal into VS Code Jupyter Notebook to get it connected to the Python 3 kernel


Could you please add "python.languageServer": "Pylance",   and "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true, to your settings.json?
